# react-native-router-flux. How to change custom navBar programmatically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a custom navBar in my scene:

```
<Scene key="myPage"
    component={MyPage}
    navBar={NavBarCustom}
    hideNavBar={false}/>
```

....

```
class NavBarCustom extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  onExitPressed(){
    App.exit();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.navBar}>

        <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
          <Image 
            style={styles.logo} 
            source={require('./../../res/ic_nav_bar.png')}/>
          <Text style={[appStyles.customFontBold, styles.title1]}>
            MY TITLE
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.centralContainer}>
          <Text style={[appStyles.customFontRegular, styles.title2]}>
            {strings.benefit_identifier}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.rightButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{padding: 7}}
            underlayColor='#b59d6e'
            onPress={() => { this.onExitPressed() }}>
            <Text style={[appStyles.customFontRegular, styles.rightButtonTitle]}>
              {strings.exit}
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It works good. So how can I change title1 of **NavBarCustom**  from my scene **MyPage**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass/send information through/with `props`:

In your render you can declare a `const` which take the `react-native-router-flux` `Actions`, set the route which to point and then set the object which to pass:

If there's a Login main file, which then redirects to a Register view then you declare the `const` `goToRegister` and then pass the `text` with its content:

```
class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const goToRegister = () => Actions.Register({text: 'From Login'}); 
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>
          Login
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={goToRegister} style={{ marginTop: 100}}>
          <Text>Go Register</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Then within your Register you receive it just within your `props` as `this.props.text`:

```
class Register extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.Login} style={{ marginTop: 100}}>
         <Text>{ this.props.text }</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

In your case you should send firstly the value of your title maybe as:

```
render() {
  const goToMyPage = () => Actions.MyPage({ title: 'Some Title'})
  ...
```

And then you're able to use it:

```
<Text style={[appStyles.customFontBold, styles.title1]}>
  { this.props.title }
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scene takes a title param

```
<Scene
  key="myPage"
  component={MyPage}
  navBar={NavBarCustom}
  hideNavBar={false}
  title="myPage"
/>
```

Comment: But I don't want to use default navBar. I want to change any component in my custom navBar.

Comment: You should be able to access the title prop and put it into your custom navbar using {this.props.title}